# Jquery on Blur and on input conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a small AutoComplete object and list my results as a list of `li` elements. I have an `this.on('input', function () {});` event that handles when you choose an item in the list and works fine. Now I want to add an `blur` event to hide results. Adding the `blur` events stops the `input` event from working.

```
$.fn.autoComplete = function () {

    this.on('input', function () {
        AutoComplete(self.val());
    });

    this.on('blur', function () {
        $('#' + settings.resultsDivId).hide();
    });

    function AutoComplete(term) {
        // ajax call
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked in the following JSFiddle - it looks like you have an error after your AutoComplete function (it ends with ");"): https://jsfiddle.net/ek5v59t6/

```
$(function() {
     $('input').autoComplete();
});

$.fn.autoComplete = function () {
     this.on('input', function () {
        console.log('input fired');
        AutoComplete($(this).val());
    });

this.on('blur', function () {
        console.log('blur fired');
    $('#results').hide();
});

function AutoComplete(term) {
    $('#results').show();
}
};
```